# Calendar Style Selection With QTableView and QSelectionModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I'm building a custom calendar view with QTableView and would like to have a QItemSelectionModel that selects cells continuously by day and week. Not sure where to start as the selection model doesn't interact with the view. The view's onCurrentChange method gives the current index, doesn't work within the selectionModel.

The view is normally connected to a more complex calendar model; the table model here is to illustrate.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, QDate
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QItemSelectionModel

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView
import typing


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QDate.longDayName(section + 1)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return index.row() * 7 + index.column() + 1

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return 6

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 7


class CalendarSelectionModel(QItemSelectionModel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CalendarSelectionModel, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)

    def currentChanged(self, current: QModelIndex, previous: QModelIndex) -> None:
        print(current, previous)


class CalendarView(QTableView):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CalendarView, self).__init__()

    # def currentChanged(self, current: QModelIndex, previous: QModelIndex) -> None:
    #     print(current)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = TableModel()

    cal = CalendarView()
    cal.setModel(model)
    sel = CalendarSelectionModel(model)
    cal.setSelectionModel(sel)
    cal.show()

    cal.resize(860, 640)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), could you explain your detail your background objective?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm not sure how to make this custom selection behavior. Selecting from index(0, 3) down to index (1, 2) should select the first row starting from 4th column and the second row from the first column to the third column for instance

Comment: Similar question with no answer here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/100692/qtableview-selection-behavior/2

Comment: I'll likely need to override the selectionCommand method https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution for a calendar style selection. Setting QAbstractItemView.NoSelection on the table and putting the selection logic in currentChanged is the way.

```
import typing

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QItemSelectionModel, QItemSelection, QModelIndex
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMouseEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QAbstractItemView


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QDate.longDayName(section + 1)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return index.row() * 7 + index.column() + 1

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return 6

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 7


class CalendarView(QTableView):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CalendarView, self).__init__()
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        self._start: typing.Union[QModelIndex, None] = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        self._start = self.indexAt(e.pos())
        self.clearSelection()
        self.selectionModel().select(self._start, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
        super(CalendarView, self).mousePressEvent(e)

    def index(self, row, col):
        return self.model().index(row, col)

    def currentChanged(self, current: QModelIndex, previous: QModelIndex) -> None:
        if self.state() == QAbstractItemView.DragSelectingState:
            self.clearSelection()
            if current.row() == self._start.row():  # we only have one row, select from start to current
                selection = QItemSelection(self._start, self.model().index(self._start.row(), current.column()))
            else:  # more than one row selected make the other 2 selections
                selection = QItemSelection(self._start, current)
                if current.row() < self._start.row():  # stencil out diagonal
                    right = QItemSelection(current, self.index(self._start.row() - 1, 6))
                    left = QItemSelection(self.index(current.row() + 1, 0), self._start)
                    selection.merge(right, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
                    selection.merge(left, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
                    if current.column() > self._start.column():
                        stencil = QItemSelection(self.index(current.row(), current.column() - 1),
                                                 self.index(current.row(), 0))
                        stencil2 = QItemSelection(self.index(self._start.row(), self._start.column() + 1),
                                                  self.index(self._start.row(), 6))
                        selection.merge(stencil, QItemSelectionModel.Deselect)
                        selection.merge(stencil2, QItemSelectionModel.Deselect)
                else:
                    right = QItemSelection(self._start, self.index(current.row() - 1, 6))
                    left = QItemSelection(self.index(self._start.row() + 1, 0), current)
                    selection.merge(right, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
                    selection.merge(left, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
                    if current.column() < self._start.column():  # stencil out diagonal
                        stencil = QItemSelection(self.index(self._start.row(), self._start.column() - 1),
                                                 self.index(self._start.row(), 0))
                        stencil2 = QItemSelection(self.index(current.row(), current.column() + 1),
                                                  self.index(current.row(), 6))
                        selection.merge(stencil, QItemSelectionModel.Deselect)
                        selection.merge(stencil2, QItemSelectionModel.Deselect)
            self.selectionModel().select(selection, QItemSelectionModel.Select)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = TableModel()

    cal = CalendarView()
    cal.setModel(model)
    cal.show()

    cal.resize(860, 640)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```